# How do I copy variable length data using bpf_probe_read() in EBPF programs?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I am trying to dump the contents of the user space buffer in read() system call by running ebpf programs on `tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_read` and `tracepoint/syscalls/sys_exit_read`. The idea is to save the user buffer address during `sys_enter_read` tracepoint, and, when the `read()` returns, inside `sys_exit_read`, copy the contents of the user buffer into a perf buffer. So I am using `bpf_probe_read()` to copy the contents from the userspace buffer. However, the verifier complains while loading. As I understand, the verifier wants to ensure a bound on the `size` argument and that prevents the load. So how do I get copying variable-length data working?

I am trying this on 5.13 kernel

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct read_exit_ctx {
    unsigned long long unused;
    int __syscall_nr;
    long ret;
};

struct read_enter_ctx {
    unsigned long long unused;
    int __syscall_nr;
    unsigned int padding;
    unsigned long fd;
    char* buf;
    size_t count;
};

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
    __type(key, int);
    __type(value, void*);
} saved_read_ctx SEC(".maps");

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_read")
int trace_read_enter(struct read_enter_ctx *ctx)
{
    int zero = 0;
    void *p = ctx->buf;
    bpf_map_update_elem(&saved_read_ctx, &zero, &p, BPF_ANY);
    return 0;
}


SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_exit_read")
int trace_read_exit(struct read_exit_ctx *ctx)
{
    char tmp_buffer[128];
    #define KEY_SIZE (sizeof(tmp_buffer) - 1)

    int zero = 0;
    void **ubuf = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&saved_read_ctx, &zero);
    if (!ubuf) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (ctx->ret <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned int ret = ctx->ret;

    // for the time being, copy to a stack buffer instead of perf buffer
    bpf_probe_read(tmp_buffer, ret & KEY_SIZE, *ubuf);
    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

```
# ./a.out
libbpf: load bpf program failed: Permission denied
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf:
R1 type=ctx expected=fp
; int trace_read_exit(struct read_exit_ctx *ctx)
0: (bf) r6 = r1
1: (b7) r1 = 0
; int zero = 0;
2: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -132) = r1
last_idx 2 first_idx 0
regs=2 stack=0 before 1: (b7) r1 = 0
3: (bf) r2 = r10
;
4: (07) r2 += -132
; void **ubuf = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&saved_read_ctx, &zero);
5: (18) r1 = 0xffff920183aa8e00
7: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
; if (!ubuf) {
8: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+8
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-136=mmmm????
; if (ctx->ret <= 0) {
9: (79) r2 = *(u64 *)(r6 +16)
10: (b7) r1 = 1
; if (ctx->ret <= 0) {
11: (6d) if r1 s> r2 goto pc+5
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R1=inv1 R2=inv(id=0,umin_value=1,umax_value=9223372036854775807,var_off=(0x0; 0x7fffffffffffffff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-136=mmmm????
; bpf_probe_read(tmp_buffer, ret & KEY_SIZE, *ubuf);
12: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r0 +0)
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R1=inv1 R2=inv(id=0,umin_value=1,umax_value=9223372036854775807,var_off=(0x0; 0x7fffffffffffffff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-136=mmmm????
; bpf_probe_read(tmp_buffer, ret & KEY_SIZE, *ubuf);
13: (57) r2 &= 127
14: (bf) r1 = r10
;
15: (07) r1 += -128
; bpf_probe_read(tmp_buffer, ret & KEY_SIZE, *ubuf);
16: (85) call bpf_probe_read#4
invalid indirect read from stack R1 off -128+0 size 127
processed 16 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 1 peak_states 1 mark_read 1

libbpf: -- END LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'trace_read_exit'
libbpf: failed to load object './EXE'
```

Edit: I initialized the `tmp_buffer[128]` array as mentioned in the comments and the bpf program loading was successful.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it's the issue, but have you tried zero-initialising your buffer before calling the helper? Something like `char tmp_buffer[128] = {0};`

Comment: @Qeole: Yes, initializing the array helped. Why did it happen? What has initializing got to do with the error? Perhaps you can write a separate answer and I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to initialise your `tmp_buffer` array before passing it to the helper**, something like:

```c
char tmp_buffer[128] = {0};
```

This is because the kernel verifier sees that you pass this array to a kernel helper. The verifier does not know what the helper does with the buffer: for all it knows, it could be a helper that sends data to user space (for instance, if you were calling `bpf_trace_printk()` instead). In such a case, sending uninitialised data to user space would present a security risk, because the uninitialised data in the buffer might be sensitive and exploitable.

For that reason, the verifier prevents you to pass the buffer, allocated on the eBPF stack, to the helper, if you have not previously initialised the data. This is what it means by `invalid indirect read from stack R1`: `R1` is the first argument passed to the helper (i.e. `tmp_buffer`), and the read is incorrect because the memory has not been initialised yet.